# compare two char in C without ASCII

Tags: c, arrays, ascii

So I want to do an encryption basically. The way I am doing this is creating two arrays and switching values. The problem I run into is, when the arrays are in just an array of characters, it doesnt work. But when I convert to the ASCII numbers, it does. Here's an example of what the two arrays would look like:

```
char* plainarray[26] = ["a","b","c"] //this would go on for the entire alphabet
char* cryptarray[26] = ["p","j","n"] //this array is the entire alphabet randomized
```

Then I have created to values for the plaintext and the encrypted text and values for the for loop. For example.

```
char plain[5] = "hello";
char* change[5] = {};
int i;
int j;
length = strlen(text); //length of string for for loop
```

Then I use two for loops to add encypted values to "crypt"

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++){
    for (j = 0; j <26; j++){
        if (plain[i] == plainarray1[j]){
            change[i] = cryptarray2[j];
        }
    }
}
```

The warning code I get when compiling is:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

One solution to my problem was using ASCII numbers in the plain text array and making it an int array. This compares the two characters, but the order of alphabet will be random for this problem, so I can't do that. Is there a better way to do this? Also I my array and assignment for the modified text ("change") proper? It doesn't give he right output.

Answer (score 2):

You’re storing arrays of pointers to strings.  Dereferencing your arrays of pointers gives you a pointer.  To store an array of characters, write:

```
const char plainarray[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', \* ... */ };
```

or

```
const char plainarray[] = "abc...";
```

The latter is not quite the same, because it has an extra byte at the end to terminate the string.

Answer (score 1):

This type:

```
char* plainarray[26] = ...
```

is an array of pointers to characters, *not* an array of characters. Change it to this:

```
char* plainarray = "abc...";
```

Then, you can access the array like this:

```
printf("%c", plainarray[0]); // prints 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing pointers to strings with `==`, which is not correct since they are obviously all at different addresses.

If you did intend to store `plainarray` and `cryptarray` as arrays of pointers to null-terminated strings, each containing one letter of the alphabet, you can use the `strcmp` function to compare them (or, since every string pointed to is one character long plus the null-terminator, you can compare position `[0]` of both strings).

In my mind it makes more sense to store `plainarray` and `cryptarray` as arrays of plain `char`, however.